# Вывести значения из функции в main

Tags: c, массивы, main

```
int cod17(int A[]) {    //Входные параметры: массив
    int j, a, n, s, k;  //Локальные переменные
    for (j = 0, a = 10; a < 30000; a++) {   //Цикл: диапазон от 0 до 30000
        for (n = a, s = 0; n != 0; n = n / 10)  //Цикл с перебором цифр числа а
        {
            k = n % 10; //отделяем поочередно последнюю цифру числа
            s = s + k; //находим сумму цифр
        }
        if (a == s * s * s) A[j++] = a; //условие проверки: если куб суммы цифр равен числу, то добавляем число в массив
    }
}
```

Comment: int result = cod17(A);

Comment: Просто используйте переданный массив — он у вас по сути и есть возвращаемое значение. Только вот само решение у вас использует знание об ответе: я о массиве конкретно из 5 чисел. Т.е. вы знаете, не решая, что их будет 5. Это не совсем корректно...

Answer (score 2):

Код семантически и логически написан очень плохо, ничего личного, это скорее как замечание к тому что в этом сложно разбираться.
Я соглашусь с Dafter, то что вы передаете и так указатель на массив, то есть изменение его элементов напрямую изменяет элементы в вашем массиве в main() (больше информации смотрите: [указатели](https://metanit.com/cpp/c/5.1.php#:%7E:text=%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC,%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%20*.)). Но что ещё подмечу, так это опасность которая кроется в передаче таких массивов. Вы или терменируйте такой массив каким либо "особенным" значением (что тоже на самом деле зависит от логики использования, что туда может попасть в случае массива int'ов), либо передавайте так же размер массива.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку ты фактически передаешь в функцию указатель, то все, что ты делаешь с массивом в функции будет меняться и в майне т.е. если я просто скопирую твой код, убрав у функции требование возвращать значение:

```
void cod17(int A[]) {    //Входные параметры: массив
    int j, a, n, s, k;  //Локальные переменные
    for (j = 0, a = 10; a < 30000; a++) {   //Цикл: диапазон от 0 до 30000
        for (n = a, s = 0; n != 0; n = n / 10)  //Цикл с перебором цифр числа а
        {
            k = n % 10; //отделяем поочередно последнюю цифру числа
            s = s + k; //находим сумму цифр
        }
        if (a == s * s * s)
            A[j++] = a; //условие проверки: если куб суммы цифр равен числу, то добавляем число в массив
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[5];
    cod17(a);
    return 0;
}
```

И добавлю точку остановки на строке создания массива a (`int a[5];`) то IDE мне покажет: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е память не заполнена и в ней мусор, но если после выполнения строки с вызовом функции (`cod17(a);`) поставить точку остановки можно увидеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е значения оказались в функции `main`, хотя мы ничего и не возвращали

Comment: Где гарантия того что ты не выйдешь за пределы памяти? Почему нельзя написать нормальный код с передачей размера массива дабы обезопасить себя от лишних действий?

Comment: Потому что я не знаю, как он создает массив в main функции, какой смысл мне чего-то мудрить, если у него это наверняка предусмотрено? К тому же я не хотел редактировать саму функцию потому что не хочу разбираться, как это работает. Я почти уверен в том, что в main он вообще создает массив диной под 1000 и не парится, но мне  было бы не удобно делать скрины в таком случае, потому я взял длину 5. Я отвечал на поставленный вопрос, а не пытался сделать красивый код